# How to migrate existing models to Wagtail Page models

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

I have a existed model,which is `EmsanWorks(models.Model)`.
I would like to have a same page model, so I copy a new model and named it `EmsanWorksPage` and changed `models.Model` to `Page`.

```
    class EmsanWorksPage(Page):
        id_works = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name_r = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        name_o = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        title_r = models.TextField()
        title_o = models.TextField()
        title_t = models.TextField()
        birth_y = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        birth_c = models.ForeignKey(EmsanPays, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='birth_c',related_name='page_emsanpays_birth_c')
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
        dest = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        media_spec = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        year = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.
        commission = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        performer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        first_perf = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        duration = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        perf_c = models.ForeignKey(EmsanPays, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='perf_c')
        context = models.TextField()
        instr = models.TextField()
        cycle = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        media_w = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        setup = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        prod_loc = models.TextField()
        prod_per = models.TextField()
        perf_tech = models.TextField()
        perf_media = models.TextField()
        publisher = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        audio = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        prog_notes = models.TextField()
        reception = models.TextField()
        editor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        phono = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        comment = models.TextField()
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
        modif = models.TextField()
        afficher = models.CharField(max_length=3)
        restricted_editors = models.TextField()

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'emsan_works'
```

However, after migrate I got this error

> OperationalError at /admin/emsanapp/emsanworkspage/
>   (1054, "Unknown column 'emsan_works.page_ptr_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: You have `managed = False` in your model's meta so any migrations will not affect this model anyway

Comment: @IainShelvington I changed it to `managed = True'  and migrated again, but I got the same error.

Comment: You deleted the previous migration and ran makemigrations again?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks! I can access to the page model now. But I can not see the existing entries there, which they existed before it changed to a page model.

Comment: @ming, you need to do data migration as well. Because the model table is changed, and existing entries is in separate model. You can read more about data migration here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/09/26/how-to-create-django-data-migrations.html